Array aligned with top of item label
I don't understand why the [t] parameter of the array environment does not do anything. I want the top of the brace to be aligned with the top of my item label but it does not work.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}    
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\hspace*{-1pt}\left\{\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
        ughjgh\\
        sdsfsfsf\\
        zfzfzfzfz
    \end{array}\right\}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}


You simply don't have enough text on your page to see its effect wrt floating environments.

[t] puts the baseline of the first line of the array (in your case the only line) on the current baseline.

note if you have more than one row in the array \left\{\begin{array}[t] rarely does what you want. see the delarray package.

@David Yes, I only put a few characters for the MWE but of course I have a much larger array. I tried to load delarray too.

@Ulrike I want the top of the brace aligned with the top of my item label (typically an example number).

delarray does exactly that

@DavidCarlisle Yes, thank you David, I was not using the proper syntax, I was at the end of the thesis and had not had the chance to check the documentation, but now I have.

Using adjustbox package to align vertically the content. With the option
valign=t ensures that the content is aligned with the top of the box. Here you not must use \hspace*{-1pt} and array.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \adjustbox{valign=t}{$\begin{Bmatrix}
        a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \\
        \int_a^b f(x) dx \\
        e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0
    \end{Bmatrix}$}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}



In my complex arrow only this worked.

@VincentKrebs Why?

Both begin and end are under the scope of the same Boolean condition. I dont know if it plays a role, but using \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t} works like a charm.

@VincentKrebs I am happy to have had luck :-)

I just think adjustbox is an amazing package...

With {BNiceArray} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}    
\begin{itemize}
\item \hspace*{-1pt}
$\begin{BNiceArray}[t]{c}
    ughjgh\\
    sdsfsfsf\\
    zfzfzfzfz
\end{BNiceArray}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}



No extra packages:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}    
\begin{itemize}
    \item \raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}{$\hspace*{-1pt}\left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
        ughjgh\\
        sdsfsfsf\\
        zfzfzfzfz
    \end{array}\right\}$}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}


With delarray.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{delarray}

\begin{document}    
\begin{itemize}
    \item \hspace*{-1pt}\begin{array}[t]\{{@{}c@{}}\}
        ughjgh\\
        ssfsfs\\
        fssffsf
    \end{array}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}

